# fill na in df.col1 on the basis of df2.col2. both dataframes are of different size

Tags: python, pandas

apologies if this has been already asked and replied to, but having searched for one whole day but could not locate the right solution. plz point me towards it, if solution already exists.

I am trying to fill na/nan values in a column in my pandas dataframe(df1). the fill values are located in another dataframe(df2) which contain the unique id's and a corresponding value. How do i match the id of df1.Prod_id (where existing value in df.item_wt is nan) and then find the corresponding value in df2.mean_wt and fill the nan value in df1.item_wt. both the dataframes are of different sizes, df1 being 80k+ rows and df2 is only 1559. the column names are also different as coming from different sources. the fill has to be done in-place.

would appreciate any pandas way, to avoid iterative looping given size of actual dataframe.

i have tried to use combine_first and map with zero success as the dataframe sizes are different, so extra rows gets no replacement.

```
data1 = {'Prod_id':['PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'PR4', 'PR2', 'PR3','PR1', 'PR4"],store=['store1','store2','store3','store6','store3','store8','store45','store23']'item_wt':[28,nan,29,42,nan,34,87,nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Item_name':['PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'PR4'],'mean_wt':[18,12,22,9]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

final df should be like:
data1 = {'Prod_id':['PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'PR4', 'PR2', 'PR3','PR1', 'PR4"],store=['store1','store2','store3','store6','store3','store8','store45','store23']'Item_wt':[28,12,29,42,12,34,87,9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: this is not same as the one pointed out as the column names are different and so the lengths of column. I have tried working with combine_first and map function but that works only until the length of df2 and whereas df1 column length is 80k rows df2 is only 1559 as it contains only unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and set numpy array created by `values` because different indices original and new Series:

```
df1['item_wt'] = (df1.set_index('Prod_id')['item_wt']
                     .fillna(df2.set_index('Item_name')['mean_wt']).values)
print (df1)
  Prod_id    store  item_wt
0     PR1   store1     28.0
1     PR2   store2     12.0
2     PR3   store3     29.0
3     PR4   store6     42.0
4     PR2   store3     12.0
5     PR3   store8     34.0
6     PR1  store45     87.0
7     PR4  store23      9.0
```

Or use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) first:

```
s = df2.set_index('Item_name')['mean_wt']
df1['item_wt'] = df1['item_wt'].fillna(df1['Prod_id'].map(s))
#alternative
#df1['item_wt'] = df1['item_wt'].combine_first(df1['Prod_id'].map(s))
print (df1)
  Prod_id    store  item_wt
0     PR1   store1     28.0
1     PR2   store2     12.0
2     PR3   store3     29.0
3     PR4   store6     42.0
4     PR2   store3     12.0
5     PR3   store8     34.0
6     PR1  store45     87.0
7     PR4  store23      9.0
```

Comment: It worked - just like magic. Thanks for helping me after a full day of despair. Have used the map function and it works flawlessly right upto to last row (82337th item) in a jiffy. I realised my mistake too while trying to use the map function. Thanks again.

Comment: Very nice. +1 from me too. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - Thank you.